# Github schedule workflow won't run every hour

Tags: github-actions

I just created a github workflow which is supposed to run every hour. However the editor shows me an error I don't understand. As far as I understand it, I can not run a workflow every 2 minutes. The minimum interval is 5 minutes. I've got an hour. Why doesn't that work?

How can I fix that?

[image]

To clarify, running every 2nd minute also doesn't work
[image]

Comment: I mean the error is pretty clear, it says that one hour is too much and five minutes is the maximum you can put here

Comment: That's not indicating that you have an _error_, it's just an informational pop-up.

Comment: If you just put 5 minutes is there any errors ?

Answer (score 1):

As [Edward Thomson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/729881/edward-thomson) mentioned, this is just an indicator, not an error message. My script works fine.